# How to access variable with strings?

Tags: python

I am having a problem accessing multiple lists with two criteria: `Case_Num` and `Case_Type`. I do not know how to fix the error of concatenate string and lists objects.

I have tried using loops and combing strings and regular integer values.Unfortunatley I keep getting same error. Any help would be appreicated

```
_2019_case_1=[]

_2019_case_2=[]

_2019_case_3=[]


Case_Num=[2019,2019,2019,2020,2020,2020,2024,2024,2024,2029,2029,2029]
Case_Type=[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]

dr = "F:\C\FE\CD\Tran\ctg"
read_files =[] 
for root, _, files in os.walk(dr):
    read_files_2="_"+Case_Num+"_case_"+Case_Type 
    for file in files:
        if file in read_files_2:
            read_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
```

---

```
Error I receive

read_files_2="_"+Case_Num+"_case_"+Case_Type
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

Comment: `Case_Num` and `Case_Type` are lists. What do you expect to happen by adding them to a `str`?

Comment: Use a dictionary instead of encoding information in the variable names → `read_files_2 = cases[(n, t)]` where `n` is one of the `Case_Num`s and `t` is one of the `Case_Type`s.

Comment: Also you should fix your spacing. You should have a space after commas and a space before and after operators (such as `+`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Comment: The longer I read this question, the less I understand what you are trying to do... Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the line where you `assign read_files_2` to a set comprehension. And best to just do this once so assign it before the loops. As stated in the comments you can use `itertools.product` as well for easily extensible changes.

```
from itertools import product

_2019_case_1=[]

_2019_case_2=[]

_2019_case_3=[]

dr = "F:\C\FE\CD\Tran\ctg"
read_files =[] 
read_files_2= {f"_{num}_case_{type}" for num, type in product((2019,2020,2024,2029), (1,2,3))}
for root, _, files in os.walk(dr): 
    for file in files:
        if file in read_files_2:
            read_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Comment: you could  use `itertools.product` on `[2019,2020,2024,2029]` and `[1,2,3]` to make it a little shorter and readable (and easily extensible to more nums and types)

Comment: `{f"_{num}_case_{type}" for num, type in product((2019,2020,2024,2029), (1,2,3))}` I get a syntax error with the quotation marks @Jab

Comment: i do not have Python 3.6

Comment: Just use the string concatenation like in your question or str.format

Comment: `read_files_2={"_{num}_case_{type}".format(num, type)for num, type in product((2019,2020,2024,2029), (1,2,3))}` I tried this but i get a `KeyError: 'num'`